# How to pass values to Angular JS Service

Tags: angularjs

I have implemented to Edit and Display values on text boxes etc but now want to transfer these code to Angular JS Service.Here is my code-

```
app.factory('fetchEmpService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http ) {
    var employees = [];
    return {

        editEmp: function (EID) {
            debugger;
            for (i in $rootScope.employees) {
                if ($rootScope.employees[i].EmpId == EID) {
                    $rootScope.newemployee = {
                        EmpId: $rootScope.employees[i].EmpId,
                        Name: $rootScope.employees[i].Name,
                        Age: $rootScope.employees[i].Age,
                        City: $rootScope.employees[i].City,
                        Gender: $rootScope.employees[i].Gender
                    };
                }
            }
        },


    };
}]);
```

I am using $rootScope instead of $scope (previously used in controller) object. Is it correct way because its returning nothing.

Comment: you should ideally use event messaging, with broadcast or emit if you are trying to pass values between controllers, or have a service in between with a model you update / read from in both controllers and is shared ...

Comment: In most cases sharing data between controllers is best accomplished in a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not good practice to store data in `$rootScope`, you're correct in thinking you need a `factory` though.

Rather than storing the employees on `$rootScope` you can store them in the service.

```
app.factory('fetchEmpService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var employees = [];

    return {
        getEmployees: function () {
            return employees;
        },
        setEmployees: function (newEmployees) {
            employees = newEmployees;
        },
        editEmp: function (EID) {
            for (var i in employees) {
                if (employees[i].EmpId == EID) {
                    return {
                        EmpId: employees[i].EmpId,
                        Name: employees[i].Name,
                        Age: employees[i].Age,
                        City: employees[i].City,
                        Gender: employees[i].Gender
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Wherever you initially set `$rootScope.employees`, change it to `fetchEmpService.setEmployees(foo);`. To get your employees, `fetchEmpService.getEmployees();`.

I'm not sure how your `editEmp` function works so that's up to you to configure, but this is a sensible enough start.